# Using Database licensed under Creative Commons Attribution v3

Tags: licensing, open-source, creative-commons

I have access to a database which data is released under Creative Commons Attribution v3.0

I understand that using this database/data requires me to give credits on information origin in different ways.

I wish to migrate this database to a different engine, and in the future use other data sources (for wish i don't know the license) to complement this data.

Can I do this as long as i keep crediting the original source of some information bits?

Answer (score 2):

The Creative Commons Attribution license is a "open" license. It gives you the right to use and modify the data in any way you see fit, as long as you give proper attribution to the source of the data.
Migrating the data to a different database engine would be fine.

For the other data sources, you need to check on a case-by-case basis if their license allows the way you want to use the data.